# renaming the files inside many folders

Tags: linux, bash, for-loop, grep, find

I have nearly `1000000` of folders of different name and each folders contain `5` files as follows.I want to rename the `5` files to different name

files inside the directories are as follows:

```
python.ps
bash.txt
ruby.txt
clang.ps
orange.txt
```

and i want to rename the files from -- to

```
python.ps  -- python3.ps
bash.txt  -- bash2020.txt
ruby.txt  --ruby19.txt
clang.ps  -- clang90.ps
orange.txt -- orange20.txt
```

i am trying `rename` command in linux but it doesnot work.So i need a supportive script in shell.Hope some expert will help me.Thanks.

```
#!/bin/sh
for file in /home/un/data/folders/*
do
rename $file
done
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, kindly do add your efforts in form of code in your question, which is highly encouraged on SO, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Find one of the files in the directory structure and then execute multiple mv commands within each directory to rename the files through -execdir.

```
find . -name "python.ps" -execdir mv python.ps python3.ps \; -execdir mv bash.txt bash2020.txt \; -execdir mv ruby.txt ruby19.txt \; -execdir mv clang.ps clang90.ps \; -execdir mv orange.txt orange20.txt \;
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use this `bash` script using an associative array:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

declare -A fmap=([range.txt]="range20.txt" \
[python.ps]="python3.ps" \
[bash.txt]="bash2020.txt" \
[ruby.txt]="ruby19.txt" \
[clang.ps]="clang90.ps" \
)

while IFS= read -rd '' file; do
   fn="${file##*/}"
   [[ -n ${fmap[$fn]} ]] && mv "$file" "${file%/*}/${fmap[$fn]}"
done < <(find /home/un/data/folders -type f -print0)
```

Answer (score 1):

I propose an alternative solution utilizing `find` with the `-exec` option.

Here, we pass a shell script as a string (`sh -c`) to be executed for each file found.

This approach offers a fair balance between readability and the ability to generalize very easily. For example, if you wanted to substitute characters in the filename, change the character casing in the filename, or increment, decrement or otherwise change numbers in the original filename; and many other situations where the destination filename is not *fixed*.

```
rename='
    basename=$(basename "{}")
    dirname=$(dirname "{}")
    case "$basename" in
        python.ps)
            dest=python3.ps ;;
        bash.txt)
            dest=bash2020.txt ;;
        ruby.txt)
            dest=ruby19.txt ;;
        clang.ps)
            dest=clang90.ps ;;
        orange.txt)
            dest=orange20.txt ;;
        *)
            exit 0 ;;
    esac
    mv "{}" "$dirname/$dest"
'
find /home/un/data/folders/ -type f -exec sh -c "$rename" \;
```

Note: in bash, you can also do the following, which allows you to put the renaming logic in a *function* and then export it so that `find` can call it. **But note that POSIX does not support exporting functions! So don't rely on this as a general solution.**

```
rename_files() {
    basename=$(basename "$1")
    dirname=$(dirname "$1")
    case "$basename" in
        python.ps)
            dest=python3.ps ;;
        bash.txt)
            dest=bash2020.txt ;;
        ruby.txt)
            dest=ruby19.txt ;;
        clang.ps)
            dest=clang90.ps ;;
        orange.txt)
            dest=orange20.txt ;;
        *)
            exit 0 ;;
    esac
    mv "$1" "$dirname/$dest"
}

export -f rename_files

find /home/un/data/folders/ -type f -exec bash -c "rename_files '{}'" \;
```